# elegant way of changes div's a tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: User List]

This is my user-list.

I need to change the red circular label.

```
$("#infoListBox .label").text($("#infoListBox a").length);
$("#infoListBox .list").bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    $("#infoListBox .label").text($("#infoListBox a").length);
});
```

When the document loads, get the number on (red) tag and change the label; next, a tag remove (change label from 21 to 20).

I want to improve this code.

My solution in a better way.

```
function getUserLength(){
    return $("#infoListBox .label").text($("#infoListBox a").length);
}
// user count
getUserLength();
$("#infoListBox .list").bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    $("#infoListBox .label").val(getUserLength());
});
```

I use jade template engine, my jade code below..

```
div(id='infoListBox').ui.fluid.vertical.menu
  div.header.item Users
    a.ui.red.circular.label
  div.list.item
    a.item Me
    a.item 조제우
    a.item 장형주
    a .item 남중민
    a.item Me
    a.item 조제우
    a.item 장형주
    a.item 남중민
    a.item Me
    a.item 조제우
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML code for the dropdown?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using MutationObserver?

Comment: $("#infoListBox .label").html($("#infoListBox a").length)

Comment: That's a sexy list ;)

Comment: @quik_silv Add Jade template codes

Comment: Maybe you should use a JS array to contain users, and modify it on certain user actions, and then modify the label based on this array's length. Or simply use some two-way data-binding lib like knockout. That would lead to much cleaner code.

Comment: I'll find MutationObserver way, thanks @epascarello.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `$("#infoListBox .label")` is representing a `label` or `span`.  So use **`.text()`**

```
$("#infoListBox .label").text(getUserLength());
```

**Updates:** no need of above too, simply

```
$("#infoListBox .list").bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    getUserLength();
});
```

Since **`getUserLength()`** *already showing the length in the red circular label*, so just call this method in **`DOMSubtreeModified`** event.

Comment: I use a tag because of my code based semantic-ui.
using `.text()` , return [Object Object]. thanks @Praveen Jeganathan

Comment: @ChangJuPark can you check `$("#infoListBox .list").bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    getUserLength();
});` since you already doing it in `getUserLength()` method.

Comment: @ChangJuPark I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function getUserLength(){
return $("#infoListBox a").length;
}

getUserLength();
$("#infoListBox .list").bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
$("#infoListBox .label").html(getUserLength());
});
```

Comment: thanks @Sidharthan but  `$("#infoListBox .list").bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){ getUserLength(); });` this is more simple